# x86 Cygwin ld not resolve references from w32api libraries at x86_64 system

Tags: c, linker, cygwin, mingw, mingw-w64

I've done fresh install of cygwin with setup-x86.exe @ Win10 LTSB 2015 x64.

I've installed `gcc-core` and `w32api-runtime` packages.

`opengl32.dll` in System32 folder is 32-bit dll.

With x86_64 install of cygwin `ld` able to find reference to wglCreateContext, with x86 - not.

```
$ gcc -o /tmp/conftest.exe /tmp/conftest.c -lopengl32
/tmp/ccec30zH.o:conftest.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `wglCreateContext'
```

conftest.c:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
char wglCreateContext ();
int
main ()
{
return wglCreateContext ();
  ;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe specify the `-m32` to forcibly indicate it's an x86 build?   Also the `-Wl,--verbose` option (no spaces in there) might be helpful - that'll tell the linker to dump information about how it's searching for libraries.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, `-m32` didn't helped. `-Wl,--verbose` showed not much useful, `attempt to open /usr/lib/w32api/libopengl32.a succeeded`, but `/tmp/ccJlXOvG.o:conftest.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to 'wglCreateContext'` and it's last message (before messages not related to libopengl32 or wglCreateContext function.

Comment: Sorry for the late response:  if you're still working this problem, what does this command output:  `nm /usr/lib/w32api/libopengl32.a | grep CreateContext`?  I think you might have only a 64-bit `libopengl32.a` library  - a 32-bit lib will have the exported name `_wglCreateContext@4`.  If your library exports the name `wglCreateContext` then it's a 64-bit library.  You'll either need to find the 32-bit one and link to that and/or figure out why `setup-x86.exe` didn't install it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, I have 32bit w32api-runtime package, it installed, I've asked  Cygwin developers at mailing list about this problem and they said that on 32bit this will not work, to work it need to include appropriate w32api headers, so as it was in autoconf test I need to change this test or state it explicitly.